# ErrorException (E_ERROR) Trying to get property 'id' of non-object In laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

How To Fix??

I use laravel 5.8 and linux os

```
public function getAverageAttribute()
{
    return (int)$this->reviews()->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->avg('rating');
}
```

Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Comment: `auth()->user()` is null if you aren't logged in, therefore there is no `id` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user isn't authenticated. You will have to first check either the user is signed in or not. As `auth()->user()` is returning null, so the error is thrown when you are trying to access the `id` property on it.

Check first either the user is authenticated or not:

```php
public function getAverageAttribute()
{
    return auth()->user() ? (int)$this->reviews()->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->avg('rating') : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debug your code, and you’ll see, what’s wrong.
E_ERROR notice, in your case is “trying to get property of non-object”, that the following piece of code returns non-object entity.

```
auth()->user()->id
```

var_dump this piece of code, and check what type actually returns.

Comment: hmmm it is null